# "powerd" using 104% of my CPU at all times, does not allow my MacBook to sleep

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

Basically summarized in the title. MacBook Pro 2019 (1.4 GHz, i5, 16 GB, Catalina) stopped sleeping after I left it to rest/when I clicked the sleep icon. After some troubleshooting on my own, I found in Activity Monitor that the "powerd" daemon is constantly using ~104% of my CPU. I have done a large number of suggested things, from resetting my SMC and PRAM to booting in Safe Mode under guidance of Apple support. Not sure what to do right now, as my computer is always very hot and never sleeps, which is a lot more annoying than seems. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me.  In Terminal, type:

```
sudo pmset schedule cancelall
```

Comment: It worked! powerd was keeping my macbook hot even at night "at sleep". Fixed now.